# Batch file for loop to unzip files and get timestamps of zip file contents

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I have a daily process which generates some zip files out of files that are being created by other processes. I need to create a daily log file which indicates the timestamps the contents of one specific file of each zip file that is found.

I created the following batch script which seemed to work yesterday on my test system, but not anymore today, no idea why...

```
set VersionDirectory=C:\Test\VersionX\
set ResultOutputFile=C:\Test\LogFile.txt

for /f %%f in ('dir /b %VersionDirectory%\Installable\Packages\pattern*.zip') do (
    mkdir %temp%\%%f\
    unzip -extract -dir %VersionDirectory%\Installable\Packages\%%f %temp%\%%f\ > nul
    for %%a in (%temp%\%%f\InstallScript.xml) do set InstallScriptXMLDate=%%~ta
    rmdir /s /q %temp%\%%f\
    echo       %%f [package from %InstallScriptXMLDate%] >> %ResultOutputFile%
)
```

Short summary of what this file is supposed to do:

1. Loop through each pattern*.zip file in C:\Test\VersionX\ directory
2. unzip this file to the %temp%\%%f directory (where %%f is the filename)
3. Get the timestamp of the %temp%\%%f\InstallScript.xml and put it in the %InstallScriptXMLDate% variable
4. Delete the %temp%\%%f directory
5. Echo the filename (%%f) and timestamp (%InstallScriptXMLDate%) into the log file

As of now the log file just contains the filenames, followed by the string '[package from ]' string, but missing the actual date timestamp

The unzipping and removing of the zip files is working flawlessly, it's just the timestamp that's not being set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting a variable and using it in the same block. This cannot work in `cmd` because environment variables are expanded when a statement is *parsed* not when it's executed. So when the loop is run *all* variables have already been replaced with the values they had *before* the loop.

Put

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the start of your batch and use `!InstallScriptXmlDate!` instead of `%InstallScriptXmlDate%`.

Another note: `for` is perfectly capable of iterating over files by itself, you almost never need to iterate over `dir /b` output with `for /f`. In fact, it can introduce problems that can be avoided with

```
for %%f in (%VersionDirectory%\Installable\Packages\pattern*.zip)
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem as well as improved my script by removing the dir /b command in the for loop!